# I want to preform a simple task on Excel, but the VBA code is getting very VERY long

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a worksheet with 6 sets of data, each with 6 columns of data. In each of the six datasets, I just want to pull out those that have a matching set number. For example,

```
001 ------ 003 ------ 002 ------ 003 ------ 003 ------ 003 ------
002 ------ 004 ------ 003 ------ 006 ------ 004 ------ 005 ------
003 ------ 005 ------ 006 ------ 007 ------ 009 ------ 013 ------
```

These are six sets of data. Only the first column in each set is of interest in this sorting macro. Here, each set shares the line "003-----". I want to write a macro that will delete any lines that don't match with the others. Is there a macro that could sort through this, and leave me with only 003-----?

I've been writing a looping macro that's saying "if Rng (A1) > Rng.Offset(,6) AND Rng > Rng.Offset(,12)... Then (delete the relevant lines)

However, for this, I'll need to cover every possibility available. Is there another more obvious approach I'm missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This macro loops through `Sheet1` and outputs all identical rows in the `Output` sheet.

```
Sub DeleteNonMatch()
    Dim i As Double
    Dim NotFound As Boolean
    Dim Inp As Worksheet, Out As Worksheet
    Dim r2 As Range, r3 As Range, r4 As Range, r5 As Range, r6 As Range

    'Defines the sheets
    Set Inp = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Sheet with original dat
    Set Out = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output") 'Output sheet

    'Defines the searchable ranges input sheet
    Set r2 = Inp.Range(Inp.Range("G2").Address & ":" & Inp.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Address)
    Set r3 = Inp.Range(Inp.Range("M2").Address & ":" & Inp.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Address)
    Set r4 = Inp.Range(Inp.Range("S2").Address & ":" & Inp.Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Address)
    Set r5 = Inp.Range(Inp.Range("Y2").Address & ":" & Inp.Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Address)
    Set r6 = Inp.Range(Inp.Range("AE2").Address & ":" & Inp.Cells(Rows.Count, 31).End(xlUp).Address)

    'Sets headers in output sheet
    With Out.Range("A1")
        .Offset(0, 0).Value = Inp.Range("A1").Value
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = Inp.Range("G1").Value
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = Inp.Range("M1").Value
        .Offset(0, 3).Value = Inp.Range("S1").Value
        .Offset(0, 4).Value = Inp.Range("Y1").Value
        .Offset(0, 5).Value = Inp.Range("AE1").Value
    End With

    'Prints identical groups to output sheet
    For i = 2 To Inp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
        NotFound = False

        If r2.Find(Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value, , , xlWhole) Is Nothing Then NotFound = True
        If r3.Find(Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value, , , xlWhole) Is Nothing Then NotFound = True
        If r4.Find(Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value, , , xlWhole) Is Nothing Then NotFound = True
        If r5.Find(Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value, , , xlWhole) Is Nothing Then NotFound = True
        If r6.Find(Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value, , , xlWhole) Is Nothing Then NotFound = True

        If NotFound = False Then
            With Out.Cells(Out.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
                .Offset(0, 0).Value = Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Offset(0, 2).Value = Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Offset(0, 3).Value = Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Offset(0, 4).Value = Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value
                .Offset(0, 5).Value = Inp.Cells(i, 1).Value
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you're close, but misunderstanding the problem. This data is all on one worksheet, with the six sets being the six grouped columns listed in the question. I want to delete each "group" of [00x ------] until I'm only left with rows of identical "groups". In this case, I'll be left with 


      003-----  003------  003-----    003-----   003-----   003-----

Does this make sense?

Comment: I see. I have changed the code and hopefully this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the update! The macro is running, but I'm not seeing anything happen other than the headers being printed on the Output sheet. I do a better job of explaining the problem here, if this helps clarify some things

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952973/ii-have-six-lists-in-excel-and-i-want-to-match-them-based-on-the-first-item-of

Comment: I have assumed that your six columns with data where columns A, B, ..., F. Maybe this isn't the case?

Comment: Yes! We're getting closer now. The cells with identical values are being pasted over to the other sheet, but I need the other cells in each group too. See this link for an example. When the BC0000 numbers are identical in a particular set, I want to copy the five adjacent cells over too. I guess it's a minor change I need to make to your code, but could you advise me on where to start? I am a beginner to VBA...

http://i.imgur.com/aGwyl9F.png

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify what columns the `BC0000` numbers are in?

Comment: They are in A, G, M, S, Y, and AE

Comment: I have updated the code again to compare values in the above mentioned columns.

Comment: Hmm, now there is nothing being printed to the Output sheet, but something is happening... Let me go back and doublecheck the changes you made.

Comment: Changing the 7 in "Inp.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Address)"  to "2" seems to print the first cell of each group. What can I change to make it print 5 cells from each set? So G2:K2, M2:Q2, etc?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's actually not working as well as I thought. This is just pulling the BC numbers common in the first two patients. I'll hack away at it a little bit more. It's certainly in the right direction though!